# "This version of C:\TURBOC3\BIN\TCC.EXE is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running.

Tags: c++, c, cmd, windows-10

I have downloaded zip file of Turbo C++ 3.2 for my windows 10 64-bit. I can not run it in cmd because it gives mentioned error. But it perfectly runs in turbo c++. I have set environment variables. what should i do?

Comment: Download a 64 bit version?

Comment: AFIAK you have to run turbo C++ in dosbox.  In case you did not know, turbo C++ is over 20 years old and should not be used anymore unless it is part of some legacy system.  If you are being taught with it, find a better teacher/place of learning.

Comment: Why not use a modern C++ compiler? Turbo C++ 3 is going to be *wildly* out of date in terms of C++ standards, it is essentially useless in learning modern C++.

Comment: You can download Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition for free. Another good choice would be installing Cygwin or MinGW and use the open source gcc tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64Bit Windows no longer supports old 16Bit DOS applications. You [need to use doxbox to get the tool running](http://blog.bestsoftware4download.com/2010/02/how-to-install-turbo-c-on-windows-7-64bit/) or use this [updated TurboC++ version](https://turboc.codeplex.com/), which includes DOSBox and does magic for you.